# How to find orientation of a real-world surface in ARKit

Tags: ios, swift, arkit

Once I have an `ARHitTestResult`, how do I go about finding information regarding its orientation. For example, once I use hit-test to find a wall, how do I know its orientation?

The `worldTransform` matrix seems to enclose orientation information, but I find no way of extracting it.

Answer (score 0):

Once you have an `ARHitTestResult` you will get a `matrix_float_4x4`.
By accessing the 3rd Column you can get positional information.
This can then be transformed to an `SCNVector3` so you can position an `SCNNode` etc e.g:

```
 override func touchesBegan(_ touches: Set<UITouch>, with event: UIEvent?) {

    guard let touchLocation = touches.first?.location(in: augmentedRealityView),
    let hitTestResult = augmentedRealityView?.hitTest(touchLocation, types: .featurePoint),
    let resultPosition = hitTestResult.first?.worldTransform
    else { return }

    let matrixColumn = resultPosition.columns.3
    let worldVector = SCNVector3(matrixColumn.x, matrixColumn.y, matrixColumn.z)

    print("""
             X = \(matrixColumn.x)
             Y = \(matrixColumn.y)
             Z = \(matrixColumn.z)
        """)

    let sphereNode = SCNNode()
    let sphereGeometry = SCNSphere(radius: 0.1)
    sphereGeometry.firstMaterial?.diffuse.contents = UIColor.cyan
    sphereNode.position = worldVector
    sphereNode.geometry = sphereGeometry
    augmentedRealityView?.scene.rootNode.addChildNode(sphereNode)

}
```